# How to embed google map with short url

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I have a table of short google urls for different places like,

```
ID|URL
------
1|http://goo.gl/maps/7nps
2|http://goo.gl/maps/wZlPp
```

depends on param in URL I need to show embedded  map of that place in browser.

So, to embed second map I use iframe html script that google gives me:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=40.408791,-3.692586&amp;spn=0.002859,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=40.408791,-3.692586&amp;spn=0.002859,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

and it works, but it uses long url: http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&t=h&ll=40.408791,-3.692586&spn=0.002859,0.00456&z=17&output=embed

When I try to replace it with shorter link, it doesn't work:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://goo.gl/maps/wZlPp"></iframe><br />
```

How is it possible to use short link there?

Comment: It's not possible to use these links with iframe's, because the x-frame-options-header is set to SAMEORIGIN, which prevents the document from being loaded in an external iframe

Comment: I say you can lookup the destination url in your server or client and then use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look at the developer console, you get something like this:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=48.858151,2.293611&spn=0.00648,0.021973&t=h&z=16 does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

So the problem is the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It is not possible to use a short link in this case.